# Converting Integers to Roman Numerals - Java

Tags: java, methods, roman-numerals

This is a homework assignment I am having trouble with.

I need to make an integer to Roman Numeral converter using a method. Later, I must then use the program to write out 1 to 3999 in Roman numerals, so hardcoding is out. My code below is very bare-bones; it is a basic I/O loop with a way to exit while using a package for `getIntegerFromUser` we made in class.

Is there a way to assign values to Strings and then add them together when I call the method?

**Update:** I got some pseudo code from my professor to help me, and while I understand what he is trying to say, I am having some trouble with the `if`s. Will I be needing many, many `if` statements so that my converter will correctly handle the Roman numeral formatting or is there a manner in which I can do this with more efficiency? I've updated my code to reflect my placeholder method.

**Update (Oct 28 2012):** I got it working. Here's what I ended up using:

```
public static String IntegerToRomanNumeral(int input) {
    if (input < 1 || input > 3999)
        return "Invalid Roman Number Value";
    String s = "";
    while (input >= 1000) {
        s += "M";
        input -= 1000;        }
    while (input >= 900) {
        s += "CM";
        input -= 900;
    }
    while (input >= 500) {
        s += "D";
        input -= 500;
    }
    while (input >= 400) {
        s += "CD";
        input -= 400;
    }
    while (input >= 100) {
        s += "C";
        input -= 100;
    }
    while (input >= 90) {
        s += "XC";
        input -= 90;
    }
    while (input >= 50) {
        s += "L";
        input -= 50;
    }
    while (input >= 40) {
        s += "XL";
        input -= 40;
    }
    while (input >= 10) {
        s += "X";
        input -= 10;
    }
    while (input >= 9) {
        s += "IX";
        input -= 9;
    }
    while (input >= 5) {
        s += "V";
        input -= 5;
    }
    while (input >= 4) {
        s += "IV";
        input -= 4;
    }
    while (input >= 1) {
        s += "I";
        input -= 1;
    }    
    return s;
}
```

Comment: *"assign values to Strings and then add them together"*  Look to [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: `String s1 = "Hello"; String s2 = "world"; System.out.println(s1 + " "+ s2);`. Given the fact that this is a homework, you should concatenate the `String`s as in the provided code. Otherwise, if you're thinking on performance and best practices, you should use the `StringBuilder` as stated in Andrew Thompson's comment.

Comment: *"this is for homework I'm really looking for ideas and examples"*  You will learn better if people withold examples and you figure it out from ideas.

Comment: why we do not use if for case 900, 500, 90, 50, 9 and 5. Because we know 'ixix' will be 'xviii' for instance. I think it 6 jmp instruction less in output and 18 (6 times 3) char less in code

Comment: "Later, I must then use the program to write out 1 to 3999 in Roman numerals, so hardcoding is out" Except when you are doing really hardcore optimization, hardcoding such logic is never okay

Answer (score 173):

A compact implementation using Java [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and recursion:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class RomanNumber {

    private final static TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    static {

        map.put(1000, "M");
        map.put(900, "CM");
        map.put(500, "D");
        map.put(400, "CD");
        map.put(100, "C");
        map.put(90, "XC");
        map.put(50, "L");
        map.put(40, "XL");
        map.put(10, "X");
        map.put(9, "IX");
        map.put(5, "V");
        map.put(4, "IV");
        map.put(1, "I");

    }

    public final static String toRoman(int number) {
        int l =  map.floorKey(number);
        if ( number == l ) {
            return map.get(number);
        }
        return map.get(l) + toRoman(number-l);
    }

}
```

Testing:

```
public void testRomanConversion() {

    for (int i = 1; i<= 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+"\t =\t "+RomanNumber.toRoman(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am in awe with the simplicity and conciseness of this code. Hats off.

Comment: Why the TreeMap ?

Comment: @ElroyJetson TreeMap is sorting the keys by natural order. The method TreeMap#floorKey has a vital role in this solution as you can conveniently lookup the greatest key less than or equal to the given key. If there is an exact match you just return the associated roman symbol, else you just concatenate the roman symbol associated by the greatest key less than the given number to the one returned by recursively calling the function using the current number subtracting the previous greatest key found.

Comment: How would you go about creating method that turns roman back to an Int using this method?

Comment: One example number 3949 to explain this: `3949 uses 1000 - M, 
2949 uses 1000 - M, 
1949 uses 1000 - M, 
949 uses 900 - CM, 9 uses 40 - XL, 
9 uses 9 - IX, resulting to 
MMMCMXLIX`

Answer (score 36):

There is actually another way of looking at this problem, not as a number problem, but a Unary problem, starting with the base character of Roman numbers, "I". So we represent the number with just I, and then we replace the characters in ascending value of the roman characters.

```
public String getRomanNumber(int number) {
    return join("", nCopies(number, "I"))
            .replace("IIIII", "V")
            .replace("IIII", "IV")
            .replace("VV", "X")
            .replace("VIV", "IX")
            .replace("XXXXX", "L")
            .replace("XXXX", "XL")
            .replace("LL", "C")
            .replace("LXL", "XC")
            .replace("CCCCC", "D")
            .replace("CCCC", "CD")
            .replace("DD", "M")
            .replace("DCD", "CM");
}
```

I especially like this method of solving this problem rather than using a lot of ifs and while loops, or table lookups. It is also actually a quit intuitive solution when you thinking of the problem not as a number problem.

Comment: +1 - avoiding the loop is pretty and I like the idea of translating this from a numeric to unary problem. Feeling inspired so I am going to throw my hat in the ring too!

Comment: You can use `"I".repeat(number)` instead of `join("", nCopies(number, "I"))` in Java 11 or later.

Comment: Do you know how to convert numbers when text is appearing in editText? I mean if i enter `1` it appear `I` immediately. I tried `Ontextchangelistener` but it return error!

Answer (score 28):

From [Java Notes 6.0](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) website:

```
      /**
       * An object of type RomanNumeral is an integer between 1 and 3999.  It can
       * be constructed either from an integer or from a string that represents
       * a Roman numeral in this range.  The function toString() will return a
       * standardized Roman numeral representation of the number.  The function
       * toInt() will return the number as a value of type int.
       */
      public class RomanNumeral {

         private final int num;   // The number represented by this Roman numeral.

         /* The following arrays are used by the toString() function to construct
            the standard Roman numeral representation of the number.  For each i,
            the number numbers[i] is represented by the corresponding string, letters[i].
         */

         private static int[]    numbers = { 1000,  900,  500,  400,  100,   90,  
                                               50,   40,   10,    9,    5,    4,    1 };

         private static String[] letters = { "M",  "CM",  "D",  "CD", "C",  "XC",
                                             "L",  "XL",  "X",  "IX", "V",  "IV", "I" };

         /**
          * Constructor.  Creates the Roman number with the int value specified
          * by the parameter.  Throws a NumberFormatException if arabic is
          * not in the range 1 to 3999 inclusive.
          */
         public RomanNumeral(int arabic) {
            if (arabic < 1)
               throw new NumberFormatException("Value of RomanNumeral must be positive.");
            if (arabic > 3999)
               throw new NumberFormatException("Value of RomanNumeral must be 3999 or less.");
            num = arabic;
         }


         /*
          * Constructor.  Creates the Roman number with the given representation.
          * For example, RomanNumeral("xvii") is 17.  If the parameter is not a
          * legal Roman numeral, a NumberFormatException is thrown.  Both upper and
          * lower case letters are allowed.
          */
         public RomanNumeral(String roman) {

            if (roman.length() == 0)
               throw new NumberFormatException("An empty string does not define a Roman numeral.");

            roman = roman.toUpperCase();  // Convert to upper case letters.

            int i = 0;       // A position in the string, roman;
            int arabic = 0;  // Arabic numeral equivalent of the part of the string that has
                             //    been converted so far.

            while (i < roman.length()) {

               char letter = roman.charAt(i);        // Letter at current position in string.
               int number = letterToNumber(letter);  // Numerical equivalent of letter.

               i++;  // Move on to next position in the string

               if (i == roman.length()) {
                     // There is no letter in the string following the one we have just processed.
                     // So just add the number corresponding to the single letter to arabic.
                  arabic += number;
               }
               else {
                     // Look at the next letter in the string.  If it has a larger Roman numeral
                     // equivalent than number, then the two letters are counted together as
                     // a Roman numeral with value (nextNumber - number).
                  int nextNumber = letterToNumber(roman.charAt(i));
                  if (nextNumber > number) {
                       // Combine the two letters to get one value, and move on to next position in string.
                     arabic += (nextNumber - number);
                     i++;
                  }
                  else {
                       // Don't combine the letters.  Just add the value of the one letter onto the number.
                     arabic += number;
                  }
               }

            }  // end while

            if (arabic > 3999)
               throw new NumberFormatException("Roman numeral must have value 3999 or less.");

            num = arabic;

         } // end constructor


         /**
          * Find the integer value of letter considered as a Roman numeral.  Throws
          * NumberFormatException if letter is not a legal Roman numeral.  The letter 
          * must be upper case.
          */
         private int letterToNumber(char letter) {
            switch (letter) {
               case 'I':  return 1;
               case 'V':  return 5;
               case 'X':  return 10;
               case 'L':  return 50;
               case 'C':  return 100;
               case 'D':  return 500;
               case 'M':  return 1000;
               default:   throw new NumberFormatException(
                            "Illegal character \"" + letter + "\" in Roman numeral");
            }
         }


         /**
          * Return the standard representation of this Roman numeral.
          */
         public String toString() {
            String roman = "";  // The roman numeral.
            int N = num;        // N represents the part of num that still has
                                //   to be converted to Roman numeral representation.
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
               while (N >= numbers[i]) {
                  roman += letters[i];
                  N -= numbers[i];
               }
            }
            return roman;
         }


         /**
          * Return the value of this Roman numeral as an int.
          */
         public int toInt() {
            return num;
         }


      }
```

Comment: @totymedli1 It's an educational site. Hope you understood that.

Comment: That explains the 1:2 code to comment ratio. That is unrealistic.

Answer (score 26):

Use these libraries:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

The code:

```
  public static String RomanNumerals(int Int) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> roman_numerals = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    roman_numerals.put("M", 1000);
    roman_numerals.put("CM", 900);
    roman_numerals.put("D", 500);
    roman_numerals.put("CD", 400);
    roman_numerals.put("C", 100);
    roman_numerals.put("XC", 90);
    roman_numerals.put("L", 50);
    roman_numerals.put("XL", 40);
    roman_numerals.put("X", 10);
    roman_numerals.put("IX", 9);
    roman_numerals.put("V", 5);
    roman_numerals.put("IV", 4);
    roman_numerals.put("I", 1);
    String res = "";
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : roman_numerals.entrySet()){
      int matches = Int/entry.getValue();
      res += repeat(entry.getKey(), matches);
      Int = Int % entry.getValue();
    }
    return res;
  }
  public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    if(s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Testing the code:

```
  for (int i = 1;i<256;i++) {
    System.out.println("i="+i+" -> "+RomanNumerals(i));
  }
```

The output:

```
  i=1 -> I
  i=2 -> II
  i=3 -> III
  i=4 -> IV
  i=5 -> V
  i=6 -> VI
  i=7 -> VII
  i=8 -> VIII
  i=9 -> IX
  i=10 -> X
  i=11 -> XI
  i=12 -> XII
  i=13 -> XIII
  i=14 -> XIV
  i=15 -> XV
  i=16 -> XVI
  i=17 -> XVII
  i=18 -> XVIII
  i=19 -> XIX
  i=20 -> XX
  i=21 -> XXI
  i=22 -> XXII
  i=23 -> XXIII
  i=24 -> XXIV
  i=25 -> XXV
  i=26 -> XXVI
  i=27 -> XXVII
  i=28 -> XXVIII
  i=29 -> XXIX
  i=30 -> XXX
  i=31 -> XXXI
  i=32 -> XXXII
  i=33 -> XXXIII
  i=34 -> XXXIV
  i=35 -> XXXV
  i=36 -> XXXVI
  i=37 -> XXXVII
  i=38 -> XXXVIII
  i=39 -> XXXIX
  i=40 -> XL
  i=41 -> XLI
  i=42 -> XLII
  i=43 -> XLIII
  i=44 -> XLIV
  i=45 -> XLV
  i=46 -> XLVI
  i=47 -> XLVII
  i=48 -> XLVIII
  i=49 -> XLIX
  i=50 -> L
  i=51 -> LI
  i=52 -> LII
  i=53 -> LIII
  i=54 -> LIV
  i=55 -> LV
  i=56 -> LVI
  i=57 -> LVII
  i=58 -> LVIII
  i=59 -> LIX
  i=60 -> LX
  i=61 -> LXI
  i=62 -> LXII
  i=63 -> LXIII
  i=64 -> LXIV
  i=65 -> LXV
  i=66 -> LXVI
  i=67 -> LXVII
  i=68 -> LXVIII
  i=69 -> LXIX
  i=70 -> LXX
  i=71 -> LXXI
  i=72 -> LXXII
  i=73 -> LXXIII
  i=74 -> LXXIV
  i=75 -> LXXV
  i=76 -> LXXVI
  i=77 -> LXXVII
  i=78 -> LXXVIII
  i=79 -> LXXIX
  i=80 -> LXXX
  i=81 -> LXXXI
  i=82 -> LXXXII
  i=83 -> LXXXIII
  i=84 -> LXXXIV
  i=85 -> LXXXV
  i=86 -> LXXXVI
  i=87 -> LXXXVII
  i=88 -> LXXXVIII
  i=89 -> LXXXIX
  i=90 -> XC
  i=91 -> XCI
  i=92 -> XCII
  i=93 -> XCIII
  i=94 -> XCIV
  i=95 -> XCV
  i=96 -> XCVI
  i=97 -> XCVII
  i=98 -> XCVIII
  i=99 -> XCIX
  i=100 -> C
  i=101 -> CI
  i=102 -> CII
  i=103 -> CIII
  i=104 -> CIV
  i=105 -> CV
  i=106 -> CVI
  i=107 -> CVII
  i=108 -> CVIII
  i=109 -> CIX
  i=110 -> CX
  i=111 -> CXI
  i=112 -> CXII
  i=113 -> CXIII
  i=114 -> CXIV
  i=115 -> CXV
  i=116 -> CXVI
  i=117 -> CXVII
  i=118 -> CXVIII
  i=119 -> CXIX
  i=120 -> CXX
  i=121 -> CXXI
  i=122 -> CXXII
  i=123 -> CXXIII
  i=124 -> CXXIV
  i=125 -> CXXV
  i=126 -> CXXVI
  i=127 -> CXXVII
  i=128 -> CXXVIII
  i=129 -> CXXIX
  i=130 -> CXXX
  i=131 -> CXXXI
  i=132 -> CXXXII
  i=133 -> CXXXIII
  i=134 -> CXXXIV
  i=135 -> CXXXV
  i=136 -> CXXXVI
  i=137 -> CXXXVII
  i=138 -> CXXXVIII
  i=139 -> CXXXIX
  i=140 -> CXL
  i=141 -> CXLI
  i=142 -> CXLII
  i=143 -> CXLIII
  i=144 -> CXLIV
  i=145 -> CXLV
  i=146 -> CXLVI
  i=147 -> CXLVII
  i=148 -> CXLVIII
  i=149 -> CXLIX
  i=150 -> CL
  i=151 -> CLI
  i=152 -> CLII
  i=153 -> CLIII
  i=154 -> CLIV
  i=155 -> CLV
  i=156 -> CLVI
  i=157 -> CLVII
  i=158 -> CLVIII
  i=159 -> CLIX
  i=160 -> CLX
  i=161 -> CLXI
  i=162 -> CLXII
  i=163 -> CLXIII
  i=164 -> CLXIV
  i=165 -> CLXV
  i=166 -> CLXVI
  i=167 -> CLXVII
  i=168 -> CLXVIII
  i=169 -> CLXIX
  i=170 -> CLXX
  i=171 -> CLXXI
  i=172 -> CLXXII
  i=173 -> CLXXIII
  i=174 -> CLXXIV
  i=175 -> CLXXV
  i=176 -> CLXXVI
  i=177 -> CLXXVII
  i=178 -> CLXXVIII
  i=179 -> CLXXIX
  i=180 -> CLXXX
  i=181 -> CLXXXI
  i=182 -> CLXXXII
  i=183 -> CLXXXIII
  i=184 -> CLXXXIV
  i=185 -> CLXXXV
  i=186 -> CLXXXVI
  i=187 -> CLXXXVII
  i=188 -> CLXXXVIII
  i=189 -> CLXXXIX
  i=190 -> CXC
  i=191 -> CXCI
  i=192 -> CXCII
  i=193 -> CXCIII
  i=194 -> CXCIV
  i=195 -> CXCV
  i=196 -> CXCVI
  i=197 -> CXCVII
  i=198 -> CXCVIII
  i=199 -> CXCIX
  i=200 -> CC
  i=201 -> CCI
  i=202 -> CCII
  i=203 -> CCIII
  i=204 -> CCIV
  i=205 -> CCV
  i=206 -> CCVI
  i=207 -> CCVII
  i=208 -> CCVIII
  i=209 -> CCIX
  i=210 -> CCX
  i=211 -> CCXI
  i=212 -> CCXII
  i=213 -> CCXIII
  i=214 -> CCXIV
  i=215 -> CCXV
  i=216 -> CCXVI
  i=217 -> CCXVII
  i=218 -> CCXVIII
  i=219 -> CCXIX
  i=220 -> CCXX
  i=221 -> CCXXI
  i=222 -> CCXXII
  i=223 -> CCXXIII
  i=224 -> CCXXIV
  i=225 -> CCXXV
  i=226 -> CCXXVI
  i=227 -> CCXXVII
  i=228 -> CCXXVIII
  i=229 -> CCXXIX
  i=230 -> CCXXX
  i=231 -> CCXXXI
  i=232 -> CCXXXII
  i=233 -> CCXXXIII
  i=234 -> CCXXXIV
  i=235 -> CCXXXV
  i=236 -> CCXXXVI
  i=237 -> CCXXXVII
  i=238 -> CCXXXVIII
  i=239 -> CCXXXIX
  i=240 -> CCXL
  i=241 -> CCXLI
  i=242 -> CCXLII
  i=243 -> CCXLIII
  i=244 -> CCXLIV
  i=245 -> CCXLV
  i=246 -> CCXLVI
  i=247 -> CCXLVII
  i=248 -> CCXLVIII
  i=249 -> CCXLIX
  i=250 -> CCL
  i=251 -> CCLI
  i=252 -> CCLII
  i=253 -> CCLIII
  i=254 -> CCLIV
  i=255 -> CCLV
```

Comment: I would add one more condition to check if match > 0 inside for loop
if(matches > 0){
 res += repeat(entry.getKey(), matches);
      Int = Int % entry.getValue();
}

Comment: I don’t understand what this line does:

`int matches = Int/entry.getValue();`, why do you use `Int` with uppercase? I’ve never seen that kind of form before for a given Java entity...

Comment: (Edit: got it, it’s one of the parameters of the `RomanNumerals` method. Since it has an uppercase letter at the start, it gets formatted as if it were a Class Type)

Comment: Why use LinkedHashMap instead of a normal HashMap. Also why are you creating and initializing the map for every invocation? Just make it a private static final

Comment: I can't remember after 5 years.

Comment: Nice style `int Int`

Answer (score 16):

I have written a very simple solution. All we have to do is divide and find how many times a particular letter(or letter combination occurs) and append that to the StringBuilder object `sb`. We also should keep track of the remaining number (`num`).

```
public static String intToRoman(int num) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int times = 0;
    String[] romans = new String[] { "I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L",
            "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M" };
    int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500,
            900, 1000 };
    for (int i = ints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        times = num / ints[i];
        num %= ints[i];
        while (times > 0) {
            sb.append(romans[i]);
            times--;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I like André Kramer Orten's answer, very elegant, I particularly like how it avoids loops, I thought of another way to handle it also avoiding loops.

It uses  integer division and modulo on the input to select the correct index from a hard-coded set of string arrays for each unit type.

The nice thing here is you can specify exact conversions depending on if you want the additive or subtractive numeral form i.e. IIII vs IV. Here I use the   the "subtractive form" for all numbers in the form 5x-1 (4,9,14,19,40,90,etc)

It would also be trivial to extend this to allow for larger numbers by simply extending the thousands array with further additive or subtractive forms, i.e. "IV", "V" or "MMMM", "MMMMM"

For bonus points I actually make sure the number parameter is within the given  range for the problem.

```
public class RomanNumeralGenerator {
    static final int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 3999;
    static final String[] RN_M = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};
    static final String[] RN_C = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    static final String[] RN_X = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    static final String[] RN_I = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};

    public String generate(int number) {
        if (number < MIN_VALUE || number > MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "The number must be in the range [%d, %d]",
                            MIN_VALUE,
                            MAX_VALUE
                    )
            );
        }

        return new StringBuilder()
                .append(RN_M[number / 1000])
                .append(RN_C[number % 1000 / 100])
                .append(RN_X[number % 100 / 10])
                .append(RN_I[number % 10])
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.  No loops, not generating a huge String...

I tested this against a [list of roman numerals from 1 to 5000](http://www.tuomas.salste.net/doc/roman/numeri-romani.html), and this produced correct results.

I just had to adjust `RN_M` to add "MMMM" to the array.

Answer (score 9):

I think my solution is one of the more concise ones:

```
private static String convertToRoman(int mInt) {
    String[] rnChars = { "M",  "CM", "D", "C",  "XC", "L",  "X", "IX", "V", "I" };
    int[] rnVals = {  1000, 900, 500, 100, 90, 50, 10, 9, 5, 1 };
    String retVal = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rnVals.length; i++) {
        int numberInPlace = mInt / rnVals[i];
        if (numberInPlace == 0) continue;
        retVal += numberInPlace == 4 && i > 0? rnChars[i] + rnChars[i - 1]:
            new String(new char[numberInPlace]).replace("\0",rnChars[i]);
        mInt = mInt % rnVals[i];
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Concise, but still with a loop and far from readable. Line 3 in the loop is ugly - the ternary operator syntax doesn't do it any favors! Nice though so +1

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up, Fraser, but you're right about what you say about my code. Also should have used a map the way bhlangonijr did, and the recursive solution he did is so clean.

Answer (score 6):

```
private static String toRoman(int n) {
    String[] romanNumerals = { "M",  "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L",  "X", "IX", "V", "I" };
    int[] romanNumeralNums = {  1000, 900, 500,  400 , 100,  90,  50,   10,    9,   5,   1 };
    String finalRomanNum = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < romanNumeralNums.length; i ++) {
            int currentNum = n /romanNumeralNums[i];
            if (currentNum==0) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < currentNum; j++) {
                finalRomanNum +=romanNumerals[i];
            }

            n = n%romanNumeralNums[i];
    }
    return finalRomanNum;
}
```

Comment: we need to add numeral for 4 and 40 too, then it'll be a perfect program.

Answer (score 4):

```
String convert(int i){

    String ones = "";
    String tens = "";
    String hundreds = "";
    String thousands = "";
    String result ;

    boolean error = false;

    Vector v = new Vector();

    //assign passed integer to temporary value temp
    int temp=i;

    //flags an error if number is greater than 3999
    if (temp >=4000) {
       error = true;
    }

    /*loops while temp can no more be divided by 10.
        Lets say i = 3254, then temp is also 3254 at line 14.

                           3254 
          3254/10 = 25    /   \ 3254%10 = 4
                         /     \
    now temp = 25       325     4  - here 4 is added to the vector v's 0th index.
                        / \
    now temp = 32     32   5  - here 5 is added to the vector v's 1st index.
                     /  \
    now temp = 3    3    2  - here 2 is added to the vector v's 2nd index, and loop exits
                   / \        since temp/10 = 0
                  0   3  - here 3 is not added to the vector v's 3rd index as loop exits when
                            temp/10 = 0.


    */
    while (temp/10 != 0) {
        if (temp / 10 != 0 && temp <4000) {
            v.add(temp%10);
            temp = temp / 10;
        }else {     
            break;
        }
    }

    //therefore you have to add temp one last time to the vector
    v.add(temp);

    //as in the example now you have 4,5,2,3 respectively in v's 0,1,2,3 indices.


    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {

        //you see that v's 0th index has number of ones. So make them roman ones here.
        if (j==0) {
            switch (v.get(0).toString()){
                case "0" : ones = ""; break;
                case "1" : ones = "I"; break;
                case "2" : ones = "II"; break;
                case "3" : ones = "III"; break;
                case "4" : ones = "IV"; break;
                case "5" : ones = "V"; break;
                case "6" : ones = "VI"; break;
                case "7" : ones = "VII"; break;
                case "8" : ones = "VIII"; break;
                case "9" : ones = "IX"; break;
            }


            //in the second iteration of the loop (when j==1) 
            //index 1 of v is checked. Now you understand that v's 1st index
            //has the tens
        } else if (j == 1) {
            switch (v.get(1).toString()){
                case "0" : tens = ""; break;
                case "1" : tens = "X"; break;
                case "2" : tens = "XX"; break;
                case "3" : tens = "XXX"; break;
                case "4" : tens = "XL"; break;
                case "5" : tens = "L"; break;
                case "6" : tens = "LX"; break;
                case "7" : tens = "LXX"; break;
                case "8" : tens = "LXXX"; break;
                case "9" : tens = "XC"; break;
            }
        } else if(j == 2){  //and hundreds
            switch (v.get(2).toString()){
                case "0" : hundreds = ""; break;
                case "1" : hundreds = "C"; break;
                case "2" : hundreds = "CC"; break;
                case "3" : hundreds = "CCC"; break;
                case "4" : hundreds = "CD"; break;
                case "5" : hundreds = "D"; break;
                case "6" : hundreds = "DC"; break;
                case "7" : hundreds = "DCC"; break;
                case "8" : hundreds = "DCCC"; break;
                case "9" : hundreds = "CM"; break;
            }
        }   else if(j == 3){ //and finally thousands.
            switch (v.get(3).toString()){           
                case "0" : thousands = ""; break;
                case "1" : thousands = "M"; break;
                case "2" : thousands = "MM"; break;
                case "3" : thousands = "MMM"; break;

            }
        } 
    }



    if (error) {
       result = "Error!";
    }else{
        result = thousands + hundreds + tens + ones;
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: it's like hardcode ^^. The accepted answer avoid explicity code for case 1,2,3 and 5,6,7,8.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research and analysing answers above, I ended up with this:

```
package roman;

public class RomanNumbers {


public static final int[] decimal = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};
public static final String[] letters = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};

public static String stringToRoman(int num) {
    String roman = "";

    if (num < 1 || num > 3999) {
        System.out.println("Invalid roman number value!");
    }

    while (num > 0) {
        int maxFound = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < decimal.length; i++) {
            if (num >= decimal[i]) {
                maxFound = i;
            }
        }
        roman += letters[maxFound];
        num -= decimal[maxFound];
    }

    return roman;       
  }
}
```

Unit tests also passed:

```
package roman;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RomanNumbersTest {

@Test
public void testReturn1() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(1);
    String expected = "I";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReturn5() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(5);
    String expected = "V";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReturn2() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(2);
    String expected = "II";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReturn4() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(4);
    String expected = "IV";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReturn399() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(399);
    String expected = "CCCXCIX";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReturn3992() {
    String actual = RomanNumbers.stringToRoman(3992);
    String expected = "MMMCMXCII";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I am curious how this is going to end up. I'd start looking into the mapping 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10 to I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VII,IX,X ... then you might look into the rule for roman numbers: 
I,II,III are created by concatentation
V, X, L, C, D and M are symbols for 5, 10, 50, 100, 500 and 1000
The romans thought that they could save space in writing numbers by instead of writing e.g. IIII for 4  use IV (meaning: 5 minus 1 ...)
You might want to look into those rules e.g. at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals and capture them in code e.g. in a class "RomanNumbers"
If you would like to cheat you might want to follow the link http://www.moxlotus.alternatifs.eu/programmation-converter.html

Answer (score 2):

My solution is in function getRoman:

```
public  String getRoman(int number) {

    String riman[] = {"M","XM","CM","D","XD","CD","C","XC","L","XL","X","IX","V","IV","I"};
    int arab[] = {1000, 990, 900, 500, 490, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (number > 0 || arab.length == (i - 1)) {
        while ((number - arab[i]) >= 0) {
            number -= arab[i];
            result.append(riman[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: The above method does not work correctly in all cases. For the integer 3992 it prints out MMMXMII, when it should print out MMMCMXCII

Comment: it's not correct, if the input is 490, will output "XD" instead of "CDXC"

Answer (score 2):

I think if you study the theory of roman numerals carefully you don't require mappings for numbers 4,9,40 etc because the theory tells us if the roman numeral is IV = 5-1 = 4, hence when the prefix is smaller than the succeeding number in that case you have to subtract the former number from the succeeding number to get the actual value and this is what I have incorporated into my code for the problem, take a look and point out any mistakes if necessary, I followed this table to devise my logic - http://literacy.kent.edu/Minigrants/Cinci/romanchart.htm

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class RomanStringToIntegerConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        String[] romanString = br.readLine().split("");

        HashMap<String, Integer> romanToIntegerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        romanToIntegerMap.put("I", 1);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("V", 5);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("X", 10);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("L", 50);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("C", 100);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("D", 500);
        romanToIntegerMap.put("M", 1000);

        int numLength = romanString.length;
        Set<Integer> lessIndices = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numLength; ++i){
            if(i+1 < numLength){
                if(romanToIntegerMap.get(romanString[i]) < romanToIntegerMap.get(romanString[i+1]))
                    lessIndices.add(i);
            }
        }

        int num = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numLength;){
            if(!lessIndices.contains(i)){
                num = num + romanToIntegerMap.get(romanString[i]);
                ++i;
            }
            else{
                num = num + romanToIntegerMap.get(romanString[i+1]) - romanToIntegerMap.get(romanString[i]);
                i+=2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The integer representation of the roman numeral is : " + num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that it's quite easy to translate from integer to Roman Numeral, because there's always sort of 1, 5 and 10 for every digit (i.e. **I**, **V** and **X** for 1-10, **X**, **L** and **C** for 10-100 etc.) That's why I made an array of Roman Numerals to get the right letter from.

In my example, I go through the whole number one digit per time, using modulo operator to get the last digit each time. Then I form the Roman Numeral from current digit inside a switch-statement, adding it in the beginning of asRomanNumerals String. After the digit has been translated, it gets removed from the number and index used to look for letter in array gets increased with two (**IVX -> XLC**).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // number is the one to be translated into Roman Numerals
    int number = 2345;
    number = Math.min(3999, Math.max(1, number)); // wraps number between 1-3999
    String asRomanNumerals = "";

    // Array including numerals in ascending order
    String[] RN = {"I", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M" };
    int i = 0; // Index used to keep track which digit we are translating
    while (number > 0) {
        switch(number % 10) {
        case 1: asRomanNumerals = RN[i] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 2: asRomanNumerals = RN[i] + RN[i] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 3: asRomanNumerals = RN[i] + RN[i] + RN[i] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 4: asRomanNumerals = RN[i] + RN[i + 1] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 5: asRomanNumerals = RN[i + 1] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 6: asRomanNumerals = RN[i + 1] + RN[i] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 7: asRomanNumerals = RN[i + 1] + RN[i] + RN[i] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 8: asRomanNumerals = RN[i + 1] + RN[i] + RN[i] + RN[i] +asRomanNumerals; break;
        case 9: asRomanNumerals = RN[i] + RN[i + 2] + asRomanNumerals; break;
        }
        number = (int) number / 10;
        i += 2;
    }
    System.out.println(asRomanNumerals);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that a lot of solutions have been already proposed.

I guess that the following one will be short and clear:

```
public class IntegerToRoman {
    public static String intToRoman(int number) {
        String[] thousands = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};
        String[] hundreds = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
        String[] tens = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
        String[] units = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};

        return thousands[number / 1000]
                + hundreds[(number % 1000) / 100]
                + tens[(number % 100) / 10]
                + units[number % 10];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 14, 17, 20, 25, 38, 49, 63, 72, 81, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 248, 253, 799, 1325, 1900, 2000, 2456, 1715};

        final Instant startTimeIter = Instant.now();
        for (int number : numbers) {
            System.out.printf("%4d -> %8s\n", number, intToRoman(number));
        }
        final Instant endTimeIter = Instant.now();
        System.out.printf("Elapsed time: %d ms\n\n", Duration.between(startTimeIter, endTimeIter).toMillis());
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
   1 ->        I
   2 ->       II
   3 ->      III
   ...
2456 ->  MMCDLVI
1715 ->   MDCCXV
Elapsed time: 66 ms
```

Logic is quite simple:

- we just go through integer number from left to right
- and taking for each number appropriate array value (thousands, hundrets...)
- this method could convert till `3000` number

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Numeral {
        I(1), IV(4), V(5), IX(9), X(10), XL(40), L(50), XC(90), C(100), CD(400), D(500), CM(900), M(1000);
        int weight;

        Numeral(int weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    };

    public static String roman(long n) {

        if( n <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        final Numeral[] values = Numeral.values();
        for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (n >= values[i].weight) {
                buf.append(values[i]);
                n -= values[i].weight;
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public static void test(long n) {
        System.out.println(n + " = " + roman(n));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(1999);
        test(25);
        test(944);
        test(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the results of MY homework. It doesn't ensure the input is in the right range and I probably should be using `StringBuilder` (time I looked it up!) and isn't one single method. But if anyone is reading this far I'd appreciate both positive and negative feedback on it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
     *Main() allows user input and tests 1-3999
     *toRoman() breaks the number down into digits and passes them to romanLogic()
     *romanLogic() converts each digit into a the numerals that represent it.
     */
    public class RomanNumerals
    {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("give us an integer < 4000: ");        
            System.out.println("the roman numeral version is: " + toRoman(in.nextInt()));
            for (int i = 1; i<=3999; i++){
                System.out.println(i +" === "+ toRoman(i));
            }
        }
        public static String toRoman(int i){
            String output = "";
            int digits = i%10;
            int tens = (i%100)/10;
            int hundreds = (i%1000)/100;
            int thousands = (i%10000)/1000;
            return (romanLogic(thousands, "M","","")+
                    romanLogic(hundreds,"C","D","M")+
                    romanLogic(tens,"X","L","C")+
                    romanLogic(digits,"I","V","X"));
        }
        public static String romanLogic(int i, String ones, String fives, String tens){
            String result = "";
            if (i == 0){
                return result;
            } else {
                if ((i>=4)&&(i<=8)){                
                    result += fives;
                }
                if (i==9){
                    result += tens;
                }
                if(i%5 < 4){
                    while(i%5 > 0){
                        result += ones;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                if(i%5 == 4){
                    result = ones + result;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this before three years, may be it helps you:

```
public class ToRoman
{

    public static String toRoman(int number)
    {
        StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder("");
        while(number!=0)
        {
            while(number>=1000)
            {
                br.append("M");
                number-=1000;   
            }
            while(number>=900)
            {
                br.append("CM");
                number-=900;    
            }
            while(number>=500)
            {
                br.append("D");
                number-=500;    
            }
            while(number>=400)
            {
                br.append("CD");
                number-=400;    
            }
            while(number>=100)
            {
                br.append("C");
                number-=100;    
            }
            while(number>=90)
            {
                br.append("XC");
                number-=90; 
            }
            while(number>=50)
            {
                br.append("L");
                number-=50; 
            }
            while(number>=40)
            {
                br.append("XL");
                number-=40; 
            }
            while(number>=10)
            {
                br.append("X");
                number-=10; 
            }
            while(number>=9)
            {
                br.append("IX");
                number-=9;  
            }
            while(number>=5)
            {
                br.append("V");
                number-=5;  
            }
            while(number>=4)
            {
                br.append("IV");
                number-=4;  
            }
            while(number>=1)
            {
                br.append("I");
                number-=1;  
            }
        }
        return br.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println(toRoman(2000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using a **Chain of Responsiblity** pattern myself. I think it makes a lot of sense for this scenario.

```
public abstract class NumberChainOfResponsibility {
    protected NumberChainOfResponsibility next;
    protected int decimalValue;
    protected String romanNumeralValue;

    public NumberChainOfResponsibility() {
    }

    public String convert(int decimal) {
        int remainder = decimal;
        StringBuilder numerals = new StringBuilder();
        while (remainder != 0) {
            if (remainder >= this.decimalValue) {
                numerals.append(this.romanNumeralValue);
                remainder -= this.decimalValue;
            } else {
                numerals.append(next.convert(remainder));
                remainder = 0;
            }
        }
        return numerals.toString();
    }
}
```

Then I create a class extending this one for every roman numeral (1/5/10/50/100/500/1000 as well as 4/9/40/90/400/900).

*1000*

```
public class Cor1000 extends NumberChainOfResponsibility {
    public Cor1000() {
        super();
        this.decimalValue = 1000;
        this.romanNumeralValue = "M";
        this.next = new Cor900();
    }
}
```

*1*

```
public class Cor1 extends NumberChainOfResponsibility {
    public Cor1() {
        super();
        this.decimalValue = 1;
        this.romanNumeralValue = "I";
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

A class serving as an "interface" to the converter, exposing a method to convert a specific number.

```
public class Converter {
    private static int MAX_VALUE = 5000;
    private static int MIN_VALUE = 0;
    private static String ERROR_TOO_BIG = "Value is too big!";
    private static String ERROR_TOO_SMALL = "Value is too small!";

    public String convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(int decimal) {
        Cor1000 startingCor = new Cor1000();
        if (decimal >= MAX_VALUE)
            return ERROR_TOO_BIG;
        if (decimal <= MIN_VALUE)
            return ERROR_TOO_SMALL;

        String numeralsWithoutConversion = startingCor.convert(decimal);
        return numeralsWithoutConversion;
    }
}
```

And the client code (in my case a JUnit test).

```
@Test
public void assertConversionWorks() {
    Assert.assertEquals("MMMMCMXCIX", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(4999));
    Assert.assertEquals("CMXCIX", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(999));
    Assert.assertEquals("CMLXXXIX", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(989));
    Assert.assertEquals("DCXXVI", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(626));
    Assert.assertEquals("DCXXIV", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(624));
    Assert.assertEquals("CDXCVIII", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(498));
    Assert.assertEquals("CXXIII", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(123));
    Assert.assertEquals("XCIX", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(99));
    Assert.assertEquals("LI", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(51));
    Assert.assertEquals("XLIX", converter.convertThisIntToRomanNumerals(49));
}
```

See the whole example on my [Github account](https://github.com/ChrisLeNeve/interview-practice/tree/master/numerals).

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of taking 2 separate arrays, it can be done using a single array.
Also i recommend **array over Map**. Array guarantee **O(1)** complexity for getting any element in any case if we know the position.
I have used **StringBuilder** instead of **String** because of frequent append operations.

```
class Solution {
    
    public String intToRoman(int num) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        RomanDataStore arr[]=new RomanDataStore[13];
        arr[0]=new RomanDataStore(1000,"M");
        arr[1]=new RomanDataStore(900, "CM");
        arr[2]=new RomanDataStore(500, "D");
        arr[3]=new RomanDataStore(400, "CD");
        arr[4]=new RomanDataStore(100, "C");
        arr[5]=new RomanDataStore(90, "XC");
        arr[6]=new RomanDataStore(50, "L");
        arr[7]=new RomanDataStore(40, "XL");
        arr[8]=new RomanDataStore(10, "X");
        arr[9]=new RomanDataStore(9, "IX");
        arr[10]=new RomanDataStore(5, "V");
        arr[11]=new RomanDataStore(4, "IV");
        arr[12]=new RomanDataStore(1, "I");
        int itr=0;
        RomanDataStore temp=null;
        while(num!=0){
            temp=arr[itr];
            if(num>=temp.val){
                for(int i=0;i<num/temp.val;i++){
                 str.append(temp.s);   
                }
                num=num%temp.val;
            }
            itr++;
        
        }
        return str.toString();
        
    }
    
    private class RomanDataStore{
        private int val;
        private String s;
        RomanDataStore(int val, String s){
            this.val=val;
            this.s=s;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing some of the answers here I had to post this. I think that my algorithm is far the most easiest to understand and the bit of performance lost is not important even on a relatively large scale. I'm also obeying the standardized coding conventions as opposed to some of the users here.

*Average conversion time: 0.05ms (based on converting all numbers 1-3999 and dividing by 3999)*

```
public static String getRomanNumeral(int arabicNumber) {

    if (arabicNumber > 0 && arabicNumber < 4000) {

        final LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> numberLimits = 
            new LinkedHashMap<>();

        numberLimits.put(1, "I");
        numberLimits.put(4, "IV");
        numberLimits.put(5, "V");
        numberLimits.put(9, "IX");
        numberLimits.put(10, "X");
        numberLimits.put(40, "XL");
        numberLimits.put(50, "L");
        numberLimits.put(90, "XC");
        numberLimits.put(100, "C");
        numberLimits.put(400, "CD");
        numberLimits.put(500, "D");
        numberLimits.put(900, "CM");
        numberLimits.put(1000, "M");

        String romanNumeral = "";

        while (arabicNumber > 0) {
            int highestFound = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> current : numberLimits.entrySet()){
                if (current.getKey() <= arabicNumber) {
                    highestFound = current.getKey();
                }
            }
            romanNumeral += numberLimits.get(highestFound);
            arabicNumber -= highestFound;
        }

        return romanNumeral;

    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(arabicNumber 
            + " is not a valid Roman numeral.");
    }
}
```

First you have to take into account that Roman numerals are only in the interval of <1-4000), but that can be solved by a simple if and a thrown exception. Then you can try to find the largest set roman numeral in a given integer and if found subtract it from the original number and add it to the result. Repeat with the newly acquired number until you hit zero.

Comment: No -1 as that would be harsh - but "most easiest" is nonsensical in English and nested loops make this far from the clearest solution.

Comment: Also - why on earth wrap the whole function in a condition? Simply negate the test and get out early. It reduces scope and makes the whole thing clearer. `if (arabicNumber < 1 || arabicNumber > 3999) {   throw new .... }` changed my mind -1!

Comment: @Fraser downvoting because of stylistic preferences (or language pedanticism) is not cool.

Comment: @Halle Knast -  Cyclomatic complexity isn't a stylistic preference.

Comment: Please get real. The performance is not an issue here nor in any realistic scenario. By this time it's merely nitpicking in a 3 year old question for no practical improvement. I stated that the answer isn't most optimal, but it's easy to understand which is more important in this scenario than to shave off milliseconds on thought up scenarios of astronomical proportions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution based on the OP's own solution by utilizing an `enum`. Additionally, a parser and round-trip tests are included.

```
public class RomanNumber {
    public enum Digit {
        M(1000, 3),
        CM(900, 1),
        D(500, 1),
        CD(400, 1),
        C(100, 3),
        XC(90, 1),
        L(50, 1),
        XL(40, 1),
        X(10, 3),
        IX(9, 1),
        V(5, 1),
        IV(4, 1),
        I(1, 3);

        public final int value;
        public final String symbol = name();
        public final int maxArity;

        private Digit(int value, int maxArity) {
            this.value = value;
            this.maxArity = maxArity;
        }
    }

    private static final Digit[] DIGITS = Digit.values();

    public static String of(int number) {
        if (number < 1 || 3999 < number) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "Roman numbers are only defined for numbers between 1 and 3999 (%d was given)",
                    number
            ));
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Digit digit : DIGITS) {
            int value = digit.value;
            String symbol = digit.symbol;

            while (number >= value) {
                sb.append(symbol);
                number -= value;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static int parse(String roman) {
        if (roman.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("The empty string does not comprise a valid Roman number");
        }

        int number = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        for (Digit digit : DIGITS) {
            int value = digit.value;
            int maxArity = digit.maxArity;
            String symbol = digit.symbol;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxArity && roman.startsWith(symbol, offset); i++) {
                number += value;
                offset += symbol.length();
            }
        }
        if (offset != roman.length()) {
            throw new NumberFormatException(String.format(
                    "The string '%s' does not comprise a valid Roman number",
                    roman
            ));
        }
        return number;
    }

    /** TESTS */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Demonstrating round-trip for all possible inputs. */

        for (int number = 1; number <= 3999; number++) {
            String roman = of(number);
            int parsed = parse(roman);
            if (parsed != number) {
                System.err.format(
                        "ERROR: number: %d, roman: %s, parsed: %d\n",
                        number,
                        roman,
                        parsed
                );
            }
        }

        /* Some illegal inputs. */

        int[] illegalNumbers = { -1, 0, 4000, 4001 };
        for (int illegalNumber : illegalNumbers) {
            try {
                of(illegalNumber);
                System.err.format(
                        "ERROR: Expected failure on number %d\n",
                        illegalNumber
                );
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Failed as expected.
            }
        }

        String[] illegalRomans = { "MMMM", "CDCD", "IM", "T", "", "VV", "DM" };
        for (String illegalRoman : illegalRomans) {
            try {
                parse(illegalRoman);
                System.err.format(
                        "ERROR: Expected failure on roman %s\n",
                        illegalRoman
                );
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Failed as expected.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
using System;

using System.Text;

public class Test
{

public static string ToRoman(int number)
{
    StringBuilder br=new StringBuilder("");
    while(number!=0)
    {
        if(number>=1000)
        {
            br.Append("M");
            number-=1000;   
        }
        if(number>=900)
        {
            br.Append("CM");
            number-=900;    
        }
        if(number>=500)
        {
            br.Append("D");
            number-=500;    
        }
        if(number>=400)
        {
            br.Append("CD");
            number-=400;    
        }
        if(number>=100)
        {
            br.Append("C");
            number-=100;    
        }
        if(number>=90)
        {
            br.Append("XC");
            number-=90; 
        }
        if(number>=50)
        {
            br.Append("L");
            number-=50; 
        }
        if(number>=40)
        {
            br.Append("XL");
            number-=40; 
        }
        if(number>=10)
        {
            br.Append("X");
            number-=10; 
        }
        if(number>=9)
        {
            br.Append("IX");
            number-=9;  
        }
        if(number>=5)
        {
            br.Append("V");
            number-=5;  
        }
        if(number>=4)
        {
            br.Append("IV");
            number-=4;  
        }
        if(number>=1)
        {
            br.Append("I");
            number-=1;  
        }
    }
    return br.ToString();
}
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ToRoman(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
public class RomanNumerals {

    private static int [] arabic = {50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

    private static String [] roman = {"L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

    public static String convert(int arabicNumber) {

        StringBuilder romanNumerals = new StringBuilder();
        int remainder = arabicNumber;

        for (int i=0;i<arabic.length;i++) {

            while (remainder >= arabic[i]) {
                romanNumerals.append(roman[i]);
                remainder -= arabic[i];
            }
        }

        return romanNumerals.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ..with nested loops. No -1 as that would be harsh but this isn't the simplest by a long shot.

Comment: Oh, @Fraser? Do, go on. Sure, it has nested loops, but show me an example I haven't seen which is simpler and more concise than this. Enlighten me.

Comment: there are a few on this page - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39411250/74861

Comment: @Fraser the Unary solution is quite clever. Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

```
private String convertToRoman(int num) {
  String result = "";
  while(num > 0){
    if(num >= 1000){
        result += "M";
        num -= 1000;
    }else if(num >= 900){
        result += "CM";
        num -= 900;
    }
    else if(num >= 500){
        result += "D";
        num -= 500;
    }else if(num >= 400){
        result += "CD";
        num -= 400;
    }else if(num >= 100){
        result += "C";
        num -= 100;
    }else if(num >= 90){
        result += "XC";
        num -= 90;
    }else if(num >= 50){
        result += "L";
        num -= 50;
    }else if(num >= 40){
        result += "XL";
        num -= 40;
    }
    else if(num >= 10){
        result += "X";
        num -= 10;
    }else if(num >= 9){
        result += "IX";
        num -= 9;
    }
    else if(num >= 5){
        result += "V";
        num -= 5;
    }else if(num >= 4){
        result += "IV";
        num -= 4;
    }else if(num >= 1){
        result += "I";
        num -= 1;
    }

    else{
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: we know after 4 iterations that first if case will never be executed anymore. so it is better to make one whilr for 1000, 100, 10 and 1 and if for special case like 900, 500, 90, 50, 9 and 5. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep up with the technology, here's a Java 8 version using streams and a custom Collector, eliminating the need for loops or if statements:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RomanNumeral {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        IntStream.range(1, 4000).forEach(value -> System.out.println( Arrays.stream(Mark.values()).collect(new MarkCollector<Mark>(value)).toString()));
    }

    enum Mark {
        M(1000), CM(900), D(500), CD(400), C(100), XC(90), L(50), XL(40), X(10), IX(9), V(5), IV(4), I(1);

        private final int value;

        private Mark(int value) { this.value = value; }

        public int value() { return value; }
    }

    static class MarkCollector<T extends Mark> implements Collector<T, StringBuilder, StringBuilder> {

        private final int[] valueholder = new int[1];

        MarkCollector(int value) { valueholder[0] = value; }

        @Override
        public Supplier<StringBuilder> supplier() { return () -> StringBuilder::new; }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<StringBuilder, T> accumulator() {
            return (builder, mark) -> {
                builder.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(valueholder[0] / mark.value(), mark.name())));
                valueholder[0] = valueholder[0] % mark.value();
            };
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<StringBuilder> combiner() { return null; }

        @Override
        public Function<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> finisher() { return Function.identity(); }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() { return Collections.singleton(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First break the number into its decimal factors like 995 = 900 + 90 + 5  then convert each factor recursively

```
public class IntegerToRoman {
  private Map<Integer, String> romanChars = new HashMap<>();

  public IntegerToRoman() {
    romanChars.put(1, "I");
    romanChars.put(5, "V");
    romanChars.put(10, "X");
    romanChars.put(50, "L");
    romanChars.put(100, "C");
    romanChars.put(500, "D");
    romanChars.put(1000, "M");
    romanChars.put(5000, "V|");
 }

 public String intToRoman(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    int decimalFact = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = (int)Math.log10(num); i >= 0; i--) {
        int divisor = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
        decimalFact = num - num % divisor;
        result.append(convertDecimalFact(decimalFact));
        num = num % divisor;
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private String convertDecimalFact(int decimalFact){
  if(decimalFact == 0){return "";}
  int[] keyArray = romanChars.keySet().stream().mapToInt(key -> key) 
       .sorted().toArray(); 

  for(int i =0 ; i+1<keyArray.length ; i++){
      if( keyArray[i] <= decimalFact && decimalFact<= keyArray[i+1]  ){
         int bigger1stDgt = getLeftMostNum(keyArray[i+1]);
         int decimalFact1stDgt = getLeftMostNum(decimalFact);
         return decimalFact1stDgt >= bigger1stDgt-1 ? 
                intToRoman(keyArray[i+1]-decimalFact)+romanChars.get(keyArray[i+1]): 
                romanChars.get(keyArray[i])+intToRoman(decimalFact - keyArray[i]);
      }
  }      
  return "";
}

private int getLeftMostNum(int number) {
    int oneDgt = Integer.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(number).toString()
                 .substring(0, 0 +1));
    if(number<10){
        return oneDgt;
    }       
    int twoDgts = Integer.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(number).toString()
                  .substring(0, 0 +2));
    return twoDgts==10 ? twoDgts : oneDgt;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntegerToRoman solution = new IntegerToRoman();
    System.out.format(" Decimal 3 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(3));
    System.out.format("Decimal 4 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(4));
    System.out.format("Decimal 8 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(8));
    System.out.format("Decimal 58 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(58));
    System.out.format("Decimal 344 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(344));
    System.out.format("Decimal 995 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(995));
    System.out.format("Decimal 1994 -> Roman %s \n ", solution.intToRoman(1994));
}
```

}

Output is like:

Decimal 3 -> Roman III

Decimal 4 -> Roman IV

Decimal 8 -> Roman VIII

Decimal 58 -> Roman LVIII

Decimal 344 -> Roman CCCXLIV

Decimal 995 -> Roman CMXCV

Decimal 1994 -> Roman MCMXCIV

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid the loop and if with this solution:

```
public class RomanNumber {

    private final static Supplier<TreeMap<Integer, String>> romanNumerals = () -> {
        final TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put(1000, "M");
        map.put(900, "CM");
        map.put(500, "D");
        map.put(400, "CD");
        map.put(100, "C");
        map.put(90, "XC");
        map.put(50, "L");
        map.put(40, "XL");
        map.put(10, "X");
        map.put(9, "IX");
        map.put(5, "V");
        map.put(4, "IV");
        map.put(1, "I");
        return map;
    };

    private static Function<TreeMap<Integer, String>, Function<Integer, String>> numeralConverter = map -> number -> Optional
            .ofNullable(map.floorKey(number))
            .filter(number::equals)
            .map(map::get)
            .or(() -> Optional
                    .ofNullable(map.floorKey(number))
                    .map(num -> map.get(num) + RomanNumber.numeralConverter.apply(map).apply(number - num))
            ).orElse("NaN");

    public static Function<Integer, String> toRoman = numeralConverter.apply(romanNumerals.get());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
```

then

```
try {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("lettered.in"));

    int dataCollect = input.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;

    String lineInput = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataCollect; i++) {

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            lineInput = input.next();
            char lineArray[] = lineInput.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < lineArray.length; j++) {

                switch(lineArray[j]) {
                case 'A': {
                    sum += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                case 'B': {
                    sum += 10;
                    continue;
                }
                case 'C': {
                    sum += 100;
                }
                case 'D': {
                    sum += 1000;
                    continue;
                }
                case 'E': {
                    sum += 10000;
                    continue;
                }
                case 'F': {
                    sum += 100000;
                    continue;
                }
                case: 'G': {
                    sum += 1000000;
                    continue;
                }
                case 'X': {
                    System.out.println(sum);
                    sum = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                default: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFound) {
    System.out.println("File has not been found.");
}
```