# Convert Int to Roman Numeral

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my code. Help please. Here is what I have my code so far and I need to use methods. It needs to be able to take an integer 1-3999 and turn that into a roman numeral. Is there an easier way to do this than what I have done?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 3999 (0 to quit): ");
    int input = in.nextInt();
    while (input !=0 )
    {
        if(input < 0 || input > 3999){
        System.out.println("ERROR! NUmber must be between 1 and 3999 (0 to quit): ");
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 3999 (0 to quit): ");
        input = in.nextInt();
        }
        else if(input > 0){
        String roman = convertNumberToNumeral(input);
        System.out.println("The number " + input + " is the Roman numberal " + roman);
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 3999 (0 to quit): ");
        input = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    while (input == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}

// Given a Scanner as input, prompts the user to input a number between 1 and 3999.
// Checks to make sure the number is within range, and provides an error message until
// the user provides a value within range.  Returns the number input by the user to the
// calling program.
private static int promptUserForNumber(Scanner inScanner, int input) {
}

// Given a number as input, converts the number to a String in Roman numeral format, 
// following the rules in the writeup for Lab 09.  Returns the String to the calling
// program.  NOTE:  This method can possibly get long and complex.  Use the 
// convertDigitToNumeral method below to break this up and make it a bit simpler to code.
private static String convertNumberToNumeral(int input) {
    String romanOnes = ("");
    String romanTens = ("");
    String romanHundreds = ("");
    String romanThousands = ("");
    int ones = input % 10;
    int tens2 = input / 10;
    if (tens2 < 10)
    {
        tens2 = input / 10;
    }
    else {
        tens2 = tens2 % 100;
    }
    int tens = tens2;

    int hundreds2 = input / 100;
    if (hundreds2 < 10)
    {
        hundreds2 = input / 10;
    }
    else {
        hundreds2 = hundreds2 % 1000;
    }

    int hundreds = hundreds2;

    int thousands2 = input / 1000;
    if (thousands2 < 10)
    {
        thousands2 = input / 10;
    }
    else {
        thousands2 = thousands2 % 10000;
    }

    int thousands = input & 10000;
    {
        if (ones == 0)
        {
            romanOnes = ("");
        }
        else if (ones == 1)
        {
            romanOnes = ("I");
        }
        else if (ones == 2)
        {
            romanOnes = ("II");
        }
        else if(ones == 3)
        {
            romanOnes = ("III");
        }
        else if(ones == 4)
        {
            romanOnes = ("IV");
        }
        else if(ones == 5)
        {
            romanOnes = ("V");
        }
        else if(ones == 6)
        {
            romanOnes = ("VI");
        }
        else if(ones == 7)
        {
            romanOnes = ("VII");
        }
        else if(ones == 8)
        {
            romanOnes = ("VIII");
        }
        else if(ones == 9)
        {
            romanOnes = ("IX");
        }
    }
    {
        if (tens == 0)
        {
            romanTens = ("");
        }
        else if (tens == 1)
        {
            romanTens = ("X");
        }
        else if (tens == 2)
        {
            romanTens = ("XX");
        }
        else if(tens == 3)
        {
            romanTens = ("XXX");
        }
        else if(tens == 4)
        {
            romanTens = ("XL");
        }
        else if(tens == 5)
        {
            romanTens = ("L");
        }
        else if(tens == 6)
        {
            romanTens = ("LX");
        }
        else if(tens == 7)
        {
            romanTens = ("LXX");
        }
        else if(tens == 8)
        {
            romanTens = ("LXXX");
        }
        else if(tens == 9)
        {
            romanTens = ("XC");
        }
    }
    {
        if (hundreds == 0)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("");
        }
        else if (hundreds == 1)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("C");
        }
        else if (hundreds == 2)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("CC");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 3)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("CCC");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 4)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("CD");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 5)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("D");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 6)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("DC");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 7)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("DCC");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 8)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("DCCC");
        }
        else if(hundreds == 9)
        {
            romanHundreds = ("CM");
        }
    }
    {
        if (thousands == 0)
        {
            romanThousands = ("");
        }
        else if (thousands == 1)
        {
            romanThousands = ("M");
        }
        else if (thousands == 2)
        {
            romanThousands = ("MM");
        }
        else if(thousands == 3)
        {
            romanThousands = ("MMM");
        }
    }
    String roman = (romanThousands + romanHundreds + romanTens + romanOnes);
    return roman;

}

// Given a digit and the Roman numerals to use for the "one", "five" and "ten" positions,
// returns the appropriate Roman numeral for that digit.  For example, if the number to
// convert is 49 we would call convertDigitToNumeral twice.  The first call would be:
//     convertDigitToNumeral(9, 'I','V','X')
// and would return a value of "IX".  The second call would be:
//     convertDigitToNumeral(4, 'X','L','C')
// and would return a value of "XL".  Putting those togeter we would see that 49 would be the
// Roman numeral XLIX.
// Call this method from convertNumberToNumeral above to convert an entire number into a 
// Roman numeral.
private static String convertDigitToNumeral(int digit, char one, char five, char ten) {


}
```

Comment: When you get lots of else if's, consider using a switch statement instead (it improves readability, especially when several cases give the same answer).

Comment: FYI there are several good Java solutions in the answers to this question: [Converting Integers to Roman Numerals - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967896/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals-java)

Answer (score 7):

Wow! You seem to be making this way too complicated. There's a very similar problem on 4clojure.com: [Write Roman Numerals](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/104). You have a bit of extra error-checking logic here, but even so you shouldn't need nearly this much code. I solved the problem with a 10-line function in Clojure. However, given that most people aren't very comfortable with [Lisps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29), I'll give you a Python solution that I quickly translated from my Clojure solution.

```py
def to_roman(n):
  digits = [(1000, 'M'), (900, 'CM'), (500, 'D'), (400, 'CD' ),
            (100, 'C'), (90, 'XC'), (50, 'L'), (40, 'XL'),
            (10, 'X'), (9, 'IX'), (5, 'V'), (4, 'IV'), (1, 'I')]
  result = ""
  while len(digits) > 0:
    (val, romn) = digits[0] # Unpacks the first pair in the list
    if n < val:
      digits.pop(0) # Removes first element
    else:
      n -= val
      result += romn
  return result
```

Python's syntax is enough like pseudo-code that you can probably understand it even if you don't actually know Python. I'll leave it to you to translate this to Java.

---

***Responding to your comment:***

> I think my problem is using the methods, how I do it using the methods I have listed?

The comments on your methods are very clear about what they're supposed to do. You need to move all the code using the `Scanner` from `main` into `promptUserForNumber`. You'll call `promptUserForNumber` from `main` to get a valid input number.

Once you have the number, you pass it to `convertNumberToNumeral` to handle the conversion. `convertNumberToNumeral` should loop over each digit of the number and call `convertDigitToNumeral` to convert each digit to the corresponding Roman Numeral string. After [concatenating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) all the digit components together `convertNumberToNumeral` can return the complete Roman Numeral representation string as the result.

The logic of `convertDigitToNumeral` can be almost identical to the `to_roman` solution I posted above, but you only need to handle a single digit. It would look something like this:

```
def digit2roman(n, ten, five, one):
  digits = [(9, one+ten), (5, five), (4, one+five), (1, one)]
  result = ""
  while len(digits) > 0:
    val, romn = digits[0]
    if n < val:
      digits.pop(0)
    else:
      n -= val
      result += romn
  return result
```

Splitting `digits` into 2 lists might make this a little easier to convert to Java:

```
def digit2roman(n, ten, five, one):
  digitsV = [9, 5, 4, 1]
  digitsR = [one+ten, five, one+five, one]
  result = ""
  i = 0
  while i < len(digitsV):
    if n < digitsV[i]:
      i += 1
    else:
      n -= digitsV[i]
      result += digitsR[i]
  return result
```

In higher-level languages it's common to zip two sequences into a single sequence of pairs when you want to iterate over 2 sequences at the same time, but in Java you usually just iterate over the indices. You should have a simple time of translating this code using Java arrays.

Comment: I think my problem is using the methods, how I do it using the methods I have listed?

Answer (score 1):

```
static HashMap<Character, Integer> numToInt;

public static void setup()
{
    numToInt = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

// this is my trick to avoid listing the numbers
    String numerals = "MDCLXVI";
    int number = 1000;
    int factor = 2;
    for (char numeral : numerals.toCharArray()) {
        numToInt.put(numeral, number);
        number /= factor;
        factor = (factor == 2 ? 5 : 2);
    }
}

public static int romanNumeralsToInt(String numeralStr)
{
    int total = 0;
    int prevVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeralStr.length(); i++) {
        int val = numToInt.get(numeralStr.charAt(i));
        total += val - (prevVal > val && prevVal != 0 ? 0 : 2 * prevVal);
        prevVal = val;
    }
    int len = numeralStr.length();
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Just by looking at this, I think something is wrong. You set `I` to 1000, V to 500, X to 100, L to 50 (correct), C to 10, D to 5 and M to 1.

Comment: I think you want to start with `number = 1000, factor = 5`, then multiply by the factor instead of dividing.

Comment: Sorry I listed the letters backwards. Switched now. Thank you @DaftPunk.

Answer (score 1):

@DaoWen's answer is very good, but since there are so few cases for the `convertDigitToNumeral` method to handle you could just hard code all of them. Here's a simple solution using [Java's format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (using positional arguments):

```
private static final String[] digitFormats = new String[] {
  "", "%1$c", "%1$c%1$c", "%1$c%1$c%1$c", "%1$c%2$c",
  "%2$c", "%2$c%1$c", "%2$c%1$c%1$c", "%2$c%1$c%1$c%1$c", "%2$c%3$c"
};

private static String convertDigitToNumeral(int digit, char one, char five, char ten) {
  return String.format(digitFormats[digit], one, five, ten);
}
```

The format string `"%2$c%1$c%1$c"` is the same as saying `five.toString() + one.toString() + one.toString()` (assuming the format arguments are passed in the order `one`, `five`, `ten`).

Answer (score 0):

Is there an easier way?

As already suggested you can use a HashTable as a lookup for the roman codes. You can either have a larger look-up with all ten options each for ones, ten and hundreds. Or use a bit of arithmetic as in the python code in the answer to limit it to just the required ones.

If you just want your code to be more readable:

1. Condense your calculations.
2. Convert your nested ifs to a switch statement.

```
string result = "";

int ones = input % 10;
int tens = (input /10) % 10;
int hundreds = (input / 100) % 10;
int thousands = input / 1000;



switch (thousands)
{
   case 1:
       result = "M"
       break;
   case 2:
       result = "MM"
       break;

// etc ...
}

switch (tens)
{
   case 1:
       result = result + "C"
       break;
// etc ..
}

switch (hundreds)
{
// etc ..
}

switch (ones)
{
// etc ..
}

return result;
```

Comment: I'd not switch (thousands) but rather new String(new char[thousands]).replace('\0','M'); This first creates a string of empty (\0) chars and then replaces them all with an M. Same for the others

Comment: @Xesau, there are countless better ways to tackle this problem (some already suggested). As mentioned in my answer the use of switch statements was a suggestion to "make the OP's code more readable" without changing the logic.