# how to change an integer value to a roman numeral

Tags: java

how can i change an integer to a roman numeral after i am done calculating the two numbers. I cant figure out how to change the integer value to its equivalent roman numeral value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Asks the user to input two numbers along with the "+" sign in roman numerals to  find the sum of the numbers.
 *  
 * @author (Harpreet Singh)
 * Brampton Centennial Secondary School
 * @version (05/11/2013)
 */
public class RomanCalculator
{
    public static int total = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a Roman Number:> ");
    char[] roman = stdIn.nextLine().toCharArray();

    for(int i = roman.length-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        switch(roman[i])
        {
            case 'I':
            total += value(roman[i]); break;
            case 'V':
            case 'X':
            case 'L':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
            case 'M':
            if(i != 0 && (value(roman[i-1]) < value(roman[i])))
            {
                total += value(roman[i]) - value(roman[i-1]);
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                total += value(roman[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }        

    if (total>1000)
    {
        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println("ERROR ILLEGAL ENTRY!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("The Total Is: "+total);
}

public static int value(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'I':
        return 1;
        case 'V':
        return 5;
        case 'X':
        return 10;
        case 'L':
        return 50;
        case 'C':
        return 100;
        case 'D':
        return 500;
        case 'M':
        return 1000;
        default:
        return ' ';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You know what units you have - it is exactly the same as converting times in seconds to times in hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: [this](http://svn.codehaus.org/castor/adaptx/trunk/src/main/java/org/mitre/tjt/text/RomanNumberFormat.java) is a class I found online. Might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967896/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals-java) for this useful method:

```
public static String IntegerToRomanNumeral(int input)
{
    if (input < 1 || input > 3999)
        throw new InvalidInputException();

    String s = "";

    while (input >= 1000) {
        s += "M";
        input -= 1000;        
    } while (input >= 900) {
        s += "CM";
        input -= 900;
    } while (input >= 500) {
        s += "D";
        input -= 500;
    } while (input >= 400) {
        s += "CD";
        input -= 400;
    } while (input >= 100) {
        s += "C";
        input -= 100;
    } while (input >= 90) {
        s += "XC";
        input -= 90;
    } while (input >= 50) {
        s += "L";
        input -= 50;
    } while (input >= 40) {
        s += "XL";
        input -= 40;
    } while (input >= 10) {
        s += "X";
        input -= 10;
    } while (input >= 9) {
        s += "IX";
        input -= 9;
    } while (input >= 5) {
        s += "V";
        input -= 5;
    } while (input >= 4) {
        s += "IV";
        input -= 4;
    } while (input >= 1) {
        s += "I";
        input -= 1;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: how can i use this code in the program that i wrote abov

Comment: Remove your code, and call this method with the `int` you want to convert like this: `IntegerToRomanNumeral(yourInt);`

Comment: are saying to remove the method int value(char c)

Comment: @helpforICS No, the one where you convert from `int` to roman and use mine instead.

Comment: i still dont understand, im a bit confused

Comment: Can you help me get started with the code plz

Comment: can you help me with coded the part for converting the total which is an integer to a roman numeral

Comment: @helpforICS Add this method to your code, then call this method with the `int` variable you want to convert and you'll get a roman number in `string` format.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int convertRomanNumeral(String roman) {
    String modRoman = roman.replace("CM", "DCCCC");
    modRoman = modRoman.replace("CD", "CCCC");
    modRoman = modRoman.replace("XC", "LXXXX");
    modRoman = modRoman.replace("XL", "XXXX");
    modRoman = modRoman.replace("IX", "VIIII");
    modRoman = modRoman.replace("IV", "IIII");

    Map<Character, Integer> symbols = new HashMap<>();
    symbols.put('M', 1000);
    symbols.put('D', 500);
    symbols.put('C', 100);
    symbols.put('L', 50);
    symbols.put('X', 10);
    symbols.put('V', 5);
    symbols.put('I', 1);

    char[] chars = modRoman.toCharArray();
    int total = 0;
    for (char c : chars) {
        total += symbols.get(c);
    }

    return total;
}
```

If you are going to call this a lot, I'd move the initialization of `symbols` to its own method, but keeping it all in one method made it simpler to post here (IMHO).

Comment: I would go one step further an use an `enum`.

Comment: Alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24982006/883073