# How do I get my program to fetch the value assigned to the number inputed by the user?

Tags: java, string, int

Currently making a program that converts integers to Roman Numerals. I don't have much written for my code because I am trying to brainstorm how I can do this before writing much:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {


        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer and I will convert it to 
        a Roman Numeral:");
        int rn = n.nextInt();
```

That is all I have right now.

The main question is; how would I assign a certain number to a roman numeral and then output the Roman Numeral that matches the int?

An answer would be appreciated but please do not give me the completed code because I am still a beginner and would like to learn without delays. Thank you!

Comment: I think this maybe is double -posted here? --> 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967896/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals-java

Comment: For the "Roman numeral" I think you have to use a String.  You can't store I's and V's in an int, so it'll have to be a String.  You could use a char array, but that's less convenient.  Also, have a look at `StringBuilder`, which is basically a mutable string for Java.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a finite set of numbers the user can input, then you can create a `Map<int, string>` to map a number to a roman numeral. Another option, one that would work for any input, would be to create a method that can 'calculate' the roman numeral based off of an integer value.

```
public static String toRoman(int value) {
    String romanNumeral = "";
     /* ... 
        code to build romanNumeral would go here ...
        (e.g.) for (blah) ... if (blah)  ..... romanNumeral += "I"; ...
     */
    return romanNumeral;
}
```

From there you should think about what steps you take mentally to convert a number to a roman numeral, and then write code to do those steps

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to you question, but more of a code review from someone who has been around the block (Java developer for 20 years—zikes!).

Why did you choose `n` as the variable name for the Scanner? I'd suggest you call it the far more obvious `scanner`. Short variable names are reasonable if you are dealing with coordinates (`x`,`y`,`z`), or indices (`i`, `j`), but should not be the norm.

Use longer names with `camelCase` and try to be very accurate when you name things. For example, your other variable `rn` is, I assume, short for Roman numeral. But it is *not* a Roman numeral. It's a *decimal integer* that you want to convert *into* a Roman numeral.

Comment: Good point. Again, I am a beginner so constructive criticism of my code is always helpful. I will keep that in mind when writing next time.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link, you will get some idea

http://www.guideforschool.com/1930249-program-on-decimal-to-roman-number-conversion-method-2/

Comment: Good example, but i think OP wants to work it out himself, big part of learning is acquiring the mindset of solving problems on your own. There are just situations where re-inventing the wheel and failing at it is just necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't want answers, but I doubt this is the way you will have solved it. So, for your interest:

```
public static String toRomanNumeral(int i) {
    return ",M,MM,MMM".split(",")[i/1000]
         + ",C,CC,CCC,CD,D,DC,DCC,DCCC,CM".split(",")[i%1000/100]
         + ",X,XX,XXX,XL,L,LX,LXX,LXXX,XC".split(",")[i%100/10]
         + ",I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX".split(",")[i%10];
}
```