# While Loop not updating value of TreeMap

Tags: java, while-loop, hashmap, roman-numerals

I am currently trying to write a program which converts integers from 0-3999  into Roman Numerals, and I have got the basis of the code correct, as when I type e.g. 6, it produces IIIIII.  However, I want it to convert to the correct roman numeral, which would be VI.  I feel there is something wrong with my While loop, but cannot seem to figure out why the Key in my TreeMap will always be 1, meaning the numeral will always be I.  What is wrong with my code, and how do I alter it to give me the correct Roman Numeral.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public String generate(int number) {
    // System.out.println("NUMBER: " + number);
    if (number < MinNumber || number > MaxNumber) {
        System.out.println("Number is out of range");
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder romanToString = new StringBuilder();
    NavigableMap<Integer, String> romanMap = createRomanMap();
    // TreeMap<Integer, String> romanMap = createRomanMap();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entries : romanMap.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entries.getKey();
        String value = entries.getValue();

        while (number >= key) {
            number -= key;
            romanToString.append(value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Stringbuilder:  " + romanToString.toString());
    return romanToString.toString();

}
```

Comment: "I have got the basis of the code correct, as when I type e.g. 6, it produces IIIIII" => Hmm, 6 is VI, isn't it?

Comment: Well, because your first key is 1. You then decrement number until it's < 1 (i.e. 0). In the following iterations, number is always lower than the key in your map. This is trivial to discover by using a debugger. Learn to use it **now**.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yeah, but my code isn't producing those numerals, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: @JBNizet where abouts do I decrement?

Comment: `number -= key;`

Comment: I think you'll need `romanMap.descendingMap().entrySet()` or construct your `TreeMap` with a `Comparator<Integer>` that ensures reverse ordering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Integers to Roman Numerals - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12967896/5221149)

Comment: @d.j.brown this fixed my issue perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are traversing the `TreeMap` in its natural key ordering.

So consider a minimal Roman map like this, with this key ordering:

`key = 1`, `value = "I"`

`key = 5`, `value = "V"`

With the input `6` the following occurs:

First `key = 1`, first `value = "I"`, `number = 6`

In your `while` loop you have `6 >= 1 => true`, so append `"I"` and decrement `6` by the key `1`.

This then repeats for `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` until the `while` loop invariant is broken.

---

However, if the Roman map is in descending order (i.e. reverse of the natural ordering), you will get the expected behavior:

First `key = 5`, first `value = "V"`, `number = 6`

You now have `6 >= 5 => true`, so append `"V"` and decrement `6` by the key `5`, so `1`.
Then `1 >= 5 => false`, so move onto the next Roman map entry.

---

**How to achieve this?**

**Option 1**

Use the descending map view's entry set:

`Map.Entry<Integer, String> entrySet = romanMap.descendingMap().entrySet();`

**Option 2**

Construct your `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` to change the ordering of the `TreeMap`, e.g.:

`SortedMap<Integer, String> romanMap = new TreeMap<>((int1, int2) -> Integer.compare(int2, int1));`